# NoSuchWindowException when trying to get a report inside a new window

Tags: selenium, testing, groovy, geb

I have the following in my code:

```
withWindow({ title == 'Google' }) {
    report "08"
}
```

And report is leading me to the exception `NoSuchWindowException`. I've checked if that was a problem of the Window selector and it isn't,After some research I guessed that the problem was that the driver got messed in the way so I stored and switched my driver:

```
String  mainHandle= driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.switchTo().window('Google');
```

But I kept getting the same error. So I tried:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

And it is working but I need to do this dinamycally and automatically because the windows and popups that we are working with are hundreds and with different titles.

How can I achieve that in every windows that opens? We are generating the code with a external tool so I don't need to do "magic", only a  driver.get.windowUrl or something like this will work for me, I will add the concurrence later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last window handle that is opened, you can do something like this:

```
public String getLastWindowHandle() {
    Set<String> windows = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itera = windows.iterator();
    String window = null;
    while (itera.hasNext()) {
        window = itera.next();
    }
    return window;
}
```

with this handle, you can switch to the new window:

```
webDriver.switchTo().window(getLastWindowHandle());
```